# How to generate a Pdf Report which is at least above 300 pages in HP Fortify

Tags: fortify

I am able to generate a Pdf Report on HP Fortify but my condition is the report needs to be more than <300 pages. But where as I am not able to set that option on HP Fortify. Please help me if you anyone know how to resolve it ?. It's better if you share me screen shot or procedures so I can easily understand because I have just started using HP Fortify software recently. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting requirement.

This is going to come down to the number of findings that SCA finds, but the longest report is normally the **Developer Workbook** report with all options turned on.